# R - ncol dont work

Tags: r

I have matrix mydata :

```
> print (mydata)
[[1]]
             [,1]       [,2]        [,3]        [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]
  [1,] -1.3135792 -1.9975308 -0.17206531  2.63028232  0.8878497  1.0354033  2.9634842
  [2,] -1.3135792 -1.4237632 -0.17206531  2.63028232  0.8878497  1.0354033  2.9634842
  [3,] -1.3135792 -1.4237632 -0.17202468  2.63028232  0.8878497  1.0354033  2.9634842
  [4,] -1.3135792  0.3795063 -0.17151001  1.12868006  0.8878497  1.0354033  2.9634842
```

This matrix is full of number. I want know how many columns this matrix have. I use ncol

```
> print (ncol(mydata))
NULL
```

It give me NULL. Why ? It look like mydata dont have any dimensions. And when I try iterate

```
for (i in 1:7){
  z[,i] = mydata[,i] * y[i]
}
```

It give me this error : `Error in mydata[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions` Any help ?

Comment: Ur data is a list.. do ncol(mydata[[1]])

Comment: Thank you. It work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extract the data from the list using `[[`. Also, it is better to keep a check on the number of columns in `mydata` using an `if and else` condition.

```
N <- ncol(mydata[[1]])
for (i in seq_len(ncol(z))){
  if(i > N) break else z[,i] = mydata[[1]][,i] * y[i]
}
```